# Mouse not dragging to its current position on progress bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am unable to figure out why the mouse is not dragging the progress bar, I don't receive any errors when I check the console. I think the mouse is being detected that it is dragging but the progress width is not updating.

//php file

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".playingBar .progressBar").mousedown(function() {
        mouseClicked = true;
    });

    $(".playingBar .progressBar").mousemove(function(event) {
        if(mouseClicked = true) {
            timeFromOffset(event, this);
        }
    });

    $(".playingBar .progressBar").mouseup(function(event) {
        timeFromOffset(event, this);
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function(event) {
        mouseClicked = false;
    });

});

    function timeFromOffset(mouse, progressBar) {
        var percentage = mouse.offsetX / $(progressBar).width() * 100;
        var seconds = audioElement.audio.duration = (percentage / 100);
        audioElement.setTime(seconds);
    }
```

//script.js file

```
    var audioElement;
    var mouseClicked = false;

    function timeProgressBarUpdate(audio) {



 $(".progressTimer.current").text(timeFormat(audioElement.audio.currentTime));
$(".progressTimer.remaining").text(timeFormat(audioElement.audio.durati 
    on - audioElement.audio.currentTime));

        var barProgressed = (audioElement.audio.currentTime / 
    audioElement.audio.duration * 100)

        $(".playingBar .progress").css("width", barProgressed + "%");
    }

    function Audio() {

    this.currentPlaying;
    this.audio = document.createElement('audio');

    this.audio.addEventListener("canplay", function() {
        var timeLeft = timeFormat(this.duration);
        $(".progressTimer.remaining").text(timeLeft);
        //this refers to object which event is called on.
    });

    this.audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
        if(this.duration) {
            timeProgressBarUpdate()
        }
    });

    this.setTime = function(seconds) {
        this.audio.currentTime - seconds;
    }

    }
```

The mouse should be able to drag the progress bar to the width based on the start of the progress bar to the horizontal position of the mouse. This will then update the css width so that it shows the progress on screen.

Comment: Please add an example to work on. Also, check your syntax, I think that you did't really want to assign a value inside a condition when you wrote `if(mouseClicked = true)`

Comment: Did you try to include the jQuery UI plugin (`jquery-ui.min.js`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, accidentally used = instead of * at var seconds in the calculation.

This made the seconds equal to 0 which is why it was not dragging at all because it was reset to 0 on click so looked as if it was not dragging.

Thanks to those who commented to help.